# Facing Cross-Origin 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue while calling webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, cross-domain

While calling a web service which is hosted on another server, I am getting the error message below. I am calling the web service locally. It is a SOAP web service.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I don't have any access to change the code of the web service.

Please help.

Comment: The Web server running the SOAP web service you want to to get data from needs to support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). At a minimum, the Web server must send an [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header in all its responses. If that Web server doesn’t support CORS and you do not have access to change its configuration to add CORS support, then your only choice it to set up a proxy in the same origin/domain where your own application code is running.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I have not deploy this on server. Just created one html file with javascript and ajax call. So using this code I am calling webservice. So,Please help to setup a proxy in such condition.

Comment: Anyone have a easy solution that I will implement in my client side script?

Answer (score 0):

If u r using google chrome, then this will help.
Go to google chrome shortcut on desktop  -> Right click -> properties -> target add this at end "--disable-web-security"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I know this approach. But I want a permanent solution using some code at my end.